# Is there a way to have celeryd read from queues on different brokers?

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I have two sets of applications running celery and a relay between them:

APPS_A <----> RELAY <----> APPS_B

The relay is, well, a relay, passing messages between APPS_A and APPS_B. Right now, the relay has queues on two different exchanges in the same RabbitMQ node. Requirements imposed by outside forces look like they will force me to have different physical RabbitMQ nodes on each side of the relay.

I'd like to have a single celeryd worker acting as the relay. Can I configure celeryd to do this? Or am I stuck with one worker instance to foward from A to B and another to forward from B to A?

Answer (score 0):

Use two different celery workers, one for each broker.